# How do I fix this Signal SIGABRT with Firebase in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using Xcode 9, once my app builds and runs on a simulator, a signal SIGABRT is caught in the AppDelegate and the app crashes.

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

There is nothing in my ViewController right now, my AppDelegate has

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

and

```
import Firebase
```

and my Podfile has been installed in the main directory of my project. Keep in mind, I am using Firebase/Core and Firebase/Database pods. I also have my *GoogleService-Info.plist* under the Info.plist file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this : override init() {
        super.init()
        // Firebase Init
           FIRApp.configure()
    }
add this code in appdelegate.

Comment: now the signal SIGABRT is coming from the init()

Comment: Remove pod file from project.and Add pods file Again.

Comment: I just did, it had the same error

Comment: what's in the Xcode console?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same issue for 4 days I downloaded firebase the issue was I name google play list as * GoogleService-Info-22.plist*. just remember don't put dashes rename it as GoogleService-Info.plist
good luck!